# overloading operators error: no matching function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, tostring

I have this overloaded operator in my FileDir.cpp implementation file:

```
 std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, const FileDir &obj) {
        out << obj.toString();
        return out;
 }
```

This is my toString() function:

```
string FileDir::toString()

{
    std::string whatever;
    std::stringstream converter;
    converter << size;
    converter >> whatever;

    std::string combined;
    if (type == false) { 
        combined = name + " " + whatever + "kb";
    }
    if (type == true) {
        combined = name + "/" + " " + whatever + "kb";
    }
    return combined;
}
```

Here is the error I get:

```
FileDir.cpp: In function ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const FileDir&)’:
FileDir.cpp:125:25: error: no matching function for call to ‘FileDir::toString() const’
     out << obj.toString();
                         ^
FileDir.cpp:125:25: note: candidate is:
FileDir.cpp:84:8: note: std::string FileDir::toString() <near match>
 string FileDir::toString()
        ^
FileDir.cpp:84:8: note:   no known conversion for implicit ‘this’ parameter from ‘const FileDir*’ to ‘FileDir*’
```

This is my FileDir.h header file:

```
#include <sstream> 

class FileDir {
public:
    FileDir();
    FileDir(std::string nameVal, long sizeVal = 4, bool typeVal = false);
    FileDir(const FileDir &obj);
    ~FileDir();            // destructor
    long getSize() const;
    std::string getName() const;
    bool isFile() const;
    std::string rename(std::string newname); 
    long resize(long newsize);
    std::string toString();
    bool operator== (const FileDir &dir1);
    bool operator<(const FileDir &obj);    

private:
    std::string name;
    long size;
    bool type;

};
```

I think there's a problem with my toString() declaration, but I'm not sure.

How do I fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't declare `toString` as a `const` member function (a function that can be called on a `const` object).  The parameter `obj` in `operator<<` is `const`, so `toString` must be as well.

Comment: I added const to the toString declaration:

std::string toString() const;

And to the implementation:

string FileDir::toString() const {
...
}

But I still get the error.

Comment: The exact same error?  You're sure you saved all your changes?

Comment: Yeah I saved the changes for sure. On top of the errors before, there is one more now:

FileDir.cpp:84:8: error: prototype for ‘std::string FileDir::toString() const’ does not match any in class ‘FileDir’

 string FileDir::toString() const
        ^
FileDir.h:34:17: error: candidate is: std::string FileDir::toString()
     std::string toString() const;
                 ^

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner: Wild guess: could it be that the problem is you have used `string` instead of `std::string` in your function definition, and so the compiler is using another `string` type?

Comment: @FabioTurati I changed it to std::string and still have the same result.